# Which online services offer logarithmic charts for equities such as index funds and ETFs?

Tags: etf, online-tools, index-fund, online-data-source, chart

The way Google Finance does the logarithmic representation is more a cry to absurdism, rather than logarithmic. So which services offer the logarithmic valuations, not just a bit axis moving? And it would be useful to know which base they use in the presentation. Any such service around?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you don't like about Google's charts?

Comment: Google Finance shows log scale much like Yahoo Finance log and other log charts.  The vertical scale has logarithmic spacing instead of linear; it is not "axis moving".  What's the problem?

Comment: @mgkrebbs: @James Roth: how can you adjust the log scale yourself? Suppose I want to get $log_{2}(x)$ and not $ln(x)$ or suppose I want to get $log_{100}(x)$. I cannot see a way to do it.

Comment: @JP.: The log base used (10, 2, e,...) doesn't matter, because the relative spacing is the same for any of them, and the labels on the axis are always given in the corresponding non-log value, that is, are labeled with actual security prices, not their logs.  The purpose of these log charts are to visually show the relative value relationships, not communicate the numeric result of taking the log of a security price.

Comment: @mgbkrebbs: is it not a useful information for example to know when did the valuation doubled or quadrupled? It would help investigation a lot if I could modify the base to $log_{2}(x)$ when I want. Like modifying the vertical axis so that it keeps constant spacing but with valuations after operating with $log_{2}(x)$? Possible somehow? I am interested to know how many years it takes to, let say, increase 10 times in valuation or anything like that.

Comment: The main sites are designed to meet the needs of the average user, what you are requesting might be useful, but most folks don't have the math chops to know a 'log base' from the foundation of a cabin in the woods.   If you don't like what they have, then do the graphs yourself.  It's easy to download the data, see my answer below

Comment: @JP.: Visually, you can do just what you want with the standard log chart.  To see when a stock doubled, find convenient points on the chart axis, one with a value twice the other (e.g. $10 and $20).  The vertical distance that separates them represents a doubling, and the same distance will appear between any doubling, as from $17 to $34.  So visually it shows the relative valuation; you just can't get the numeric log value from the chart.  If you want that, do what Chuck suggests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The charts on nasdaq.com are log based, if you look closely you can see that the spacing between evenly incremented prices is tighter at the top of the chart and wider at the bottom.   It's easiest to see on a stock with a wide price range using candlestick where you can clearly see the grid.

I'm also not seeing the "absurdism" you indicate when I look at google finance with the settings ticked to use log on the price axis.  I see what I'd expect which is basically a given vertical differential on the price axis representing the same percentage change in price no matter where it is located.

For example if I look at GOOG from the earliest date they have (Aug 20 2004) to a nice high point (dec 7 2007) I see a cart where the gap from the the bottom of the chart (seems to be right around 100) to the 200 point, (a 100% increase) is the same as from 200 to 400 (a 100% increase) is the same as 400 to 800 (a 100# increase)

That's exactly what I expect from a 'log' chart on a financial site, each relative move up or down of the same distance, represents the same relative change in value. So I'm having difficulty understanding what your complaint is.

(note: I'm using chrome, which is the browser I'd expect to work best with any google website.  results with other browsers could of course vary)

If you want to do some other wacky math with the axis then I humbly suggest that something like Excel is your friend.   Goto the charts at nasdaq.com  get the chart displaying the period you care about, click the chart to display the unlying data, there will be an option to download the data.  cram it into excel and go wild as you want with charting it out.

e.g.

1. go to the nasdaq basic charting page, for example
   http://www.nasdaq.com/aspx/chartingbasics.aspx?symbol=MSFT&selected=MSFT
2. move your mouse on top of the chart and click
3. a new window opens that has a table with the data from the chart, and at the top is a link that says 'Download This File in Excel Format'
4. click that link.

note that step 2 links to client side javascript, so you will need javascript enabled, if you are running something like noscript, disable it for this site.  Also since the data opens in a new window, you may also need to enabled 'popups' for the site.

(and yes, I sometimes get an annoying news alert advert popup  and have to close it when the chart first appears.. oh well it pays the rent and nasdaq is not charging you so for access so such is the price for a free site. )

Comment: sorry but I cannot find the "Download Data" -button, it would be very useful to find a site that offers the graphs and then a download feature by which you can download data in your specified format such as every month's average price. I could easily graph this kind of things myself but I cannot find the data or actually, I could use Google Docs Finance API --. Anything simpler?

Comment: works on my machine..  (heh as a tester, you don't know how often I get told that, it's fun to get to say it for a change).  I'll edit the response to include more detailed steps since my initial description is apparently not clear enough.